# Finding relative distance of points to each other

Tags: geometry-nodes

I want to get each and every point's distance to every other point. I think the "merge by distance" node does what I want but, I just want to get the results and affect them (not merge) if they fall under a condition, in this case, the condition is distance. In other words, calculate the distances, find local neighbors, and affect them as I pleased.

[image]

Comment: i think Entagma did a great job explaining this here: https://youtu.be/tj6ZZYO5qPY

Comment: Yes, I have watched the video but forgot somehow. Thanks for the reminder.